# how to recover table in SYSTEM schema

Tags: oracle11g

In oracle 11g , I wrong delete system table . I try to rollback , but tables are already delete. How to recover these table without reinstall oracle 11 g.

Comment: Well, do you have a backup of your system?

Comment: no have system db backup .But I can get system db from other people.

Comment: is flashback turned on? and what table did you delete?

Comment: @steve I don't know exactly what table was delete . Because I selected all table and then select drop table command.Before successfully delete all table , I try to cancel .But Some table was deleted.Now I use Toad for Oracle professional 10.5.1.3.Where can I find flashbak option?

Comment: can you describe what exactly you did? you selected all the tables in the system tablespace to be deleted? with which user were you connected? is the database still up?

Comment: @steve I selected all tables under system schema in schema browser to drop and then rightclick -> drop table -> OK .

Comment: At this point you have an unsupported database. I'd recommend to do a crash backup, then export the user schemas. Drop the database, recreate the database and import the user schemas. But as you seem not be very familiar with Oracle, I'd highly recommend to call oracle and support. And very important don't shutdown the database, it might not come up again.

Comment: Can you look in the recyclebin?

Comment: System objects are never stored in the recycle bin.